# Is there Any API in Drools to check whether the rule is present in KieModules or not?

Tags: drools, drools-kie-server

We are using Drools as rules processing language for serving content to users. I have my service deployed on EC2 instance and I need to test that whether the rules (DRLs) are present in instance memory or not? Is there any way or API in Drools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can check whether the rule is available in the kiebase or not. You just need to know the kieBase name, the package of the rule and the rule name and then use this function.

> kieContainer.getKieBase("kiebasename").getRule("packagename","rulename").getName()